# How can I browse CTAN packages by date?

Tags: packages, ctan

I would like to browse CTAN to find font packages added recently.

Can I do thin on CTAN or using any kind of software?

Comment: You can consult the archives of the mailing list at https://lists.dante.de/mailman/listinfo/ctan-ann

Comment: But these mailing lists do not contain CTAN topics.

Comment: You can use the JSON API to query this information and compute the respective packages programatically…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Python 3 script to call the CTAN JSON API and sort packages by their update date (if it written):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
pd.options.display.max_rows = None

url = "http://www.ctan.org/json/2.0/topic/font?ref=true"
df = pd.read_json(url)

for idx in range(df.shape[0]):
    pkgurl = 'http://www.ctan.org/json/2.0/pkg/' + df['packages'][idx]
    pkgdf = pd.read_json(pkgurl, typ='frame', orient='index')
    try:
        date = pkgdf.loc[["version"],:][0][0]['date']
        df.at[idx, 'date'] = date
    except Exception:
        df.at[idx, 'date'] = np.nan

df[['packages', 'date']].dropna().sort_values(by=['date'], ascending=False)
```

You can run the script online, for example, on the [Jupyter page](https://jupyter.org/try).

- On the page, under 'Try Jupyter' click 'JupyterLab'.
- A Binder page will open, displaying a deployment log.
- When Binder finishes loading, a JupyterLab home page will appear.
- On the home page, under 'Notebook' click 'Python 3'.
- Paste the code and click the 'Play/Run' button.
- It will take some time to process the data and show the results table.

Comment: Interesting.  What is this script's instruction manual?

Comment: The easiest way is to run it in a Python 3 JupyterLab notebook, e.g. https://jupyter.org/try

Comment: Can you explain this in detail in your answer because I have never used this?

Comment: It took a lot of time, but I've updated the answer with an explanation how to run the script online.